# AWK how to put the output of a command to a variable

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I am trying to get the number of the line where the word "nel" comes as the variable "line" from the prueba.txt with help of the progtesis.awk command I am writing.

I am running this in the terminal:

```
awk -f progtesis.awk prueba.txt
```

And progtesis sees as follow:

```
line=$(awk -f '/nel/{print NR}' FILENAME}

echo "$line"
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: If you want to assign a variable *in the shell that called you*, as opposed to assigning an awk variable, without changing that parent process you simply can't do that at all (from any program invoked as a subprocess, child, or otherwise outside the shell or other interpreter in which you intend the variable to be defined).

Comment: It'd be like asking a Python program to assign a variable in the Java program that started it -- there simply isn't any communication mechanism there, unless you write something into the Java program for the purpose. awk and bash are two separate languages; the only coupling is through your regular, documented interfaces (stdin; stdout; stderr; environment variables copied only from parent->child and not back from child to parent; etc).

Comment: That said, I'm not certain that my interpretation above is actually what you're trying to ask -- could you try to clear up the English to be more explicit about the distinction between the behavior you *have* and the behavior you *want*?

Comment: Post a brief program that demonstrates your problem, complete with sample input and expected output, i.e. a [mcve]. Right now there's several different things your question could mean (I suspect you're trying to use shell syntax and call shell commands from within an awk script but idk...).

Answer (score 1):

No need of an external awk script :

```
line=$(awk '/nel/ {print NR; exit}' "${filename}")
echo "${line}"
```

will display number of first line matching `/nel/`.

Otherwise if `progtesis.awk` contains

```
/nel/ {print NR; exit}
```

The bash commands can be

```
line=$(awk progtesis.awk "${filename}")
echo "${line}"
```